# How can I delay my program so there's a pause in between text?

Tags: java, text, delay

Example of my code:

```
System.out.println("Why hello there!");
System.out.println("Welcome to 'Ancient Battles and Adventures!");
***DELAY WOULD GO HERE***
System.out.println("Now, what is your name?");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Why hello there!");
        System.out.println("Welcome to 'Ancient Battles and Adventures!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(x);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Now, what is your name?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for success

```
class ex 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Why hello there!");
        System.out.println("Welcome to 'Ancient Battles and Adventures!");
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);// here you can delay for one second
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Now, what is your name?");
    }
}
```